# solving double integrals with two variables

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I have an exam tomorrow that involves solving integrals like

$$ \oint{Q dy + P dx}$$

by converting them to

$$ \int{ \bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\bigg)dy dx}$$

Could someone tell me what this method called and where I could find some problems to solve in this subject, thanks.

Comment: Do you know Green's theorem?

Comment: just looked it up on Google, is that what it is called?

Comment: Yes it is. You need to know about line integrals.